# jsfiddle can't show the proper GUI of EXTJS 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4, jsfiddle

```
var loginForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
           frame: true,
           border: false,
           labelWidth: 75,
           items: [{
             xtype: 'textfield',
             width: 190,
             id: 'username',
             fieldLabel: 'User name'
           },{
             xtype: 'textfield',
             width: 190,
             id: 'password',
             fieldLabel: 'Password',
             inputType: 'password',
             submitValue: false
           },{
             xtype: 'hidden',
             id: 'challenge',
             value: "<?php echo $challenge; ?>",
             submitValue: false
           }]
         });

         var loginWindow = new Ext.Window({
           title: 'Login',
           layout: 'fit',
           closable: false,
           resizable: false,
           draggable: false,
           border: false,
           height: 125,
           width: 300,
           items: [loginForm]
         });
         loginWindow.show();
```

how come my login form can't show the proper GUI on here http://jsfiddle.net/WM9DD/83/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to include the `CSS` file in the managed resources or html section:
I updated the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/WM9DD/84/

Comment: is it just me or have all EXT jsfiddles stopped working

Comment: Yep, looks like jsfiddle lost the resource location of this file: http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/extjs-4.1.0/ext-all.js Hopefully its a temporary snafu.